# Rellenar tabla en HTML recibiendo un archivo txt con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5

Actualmente estoy aprendiendo javascript y estoy haciendo un ejercicio que se basa en que el usuario pueda seleccionar un archivo de manera local con formato txt; este archivo contiene una tabla, esta tabla se tendrá que mostrar en la vista  para posteriormente ser almacenada en la base de datos.
He aquí mi duda: he buscado muchas maneras de hacerlo, sin resultado alguno; he intentado buscar la manera de convertir el txt en un json y de ahí pintar la tabla desde el js, pero igual no he encontrado la forma de hacerlo.

El documento txt está escrito de la siguiente manera, está separado por espacios:

=========DOCUMENTO DE TEXTO ==========

```
CAMPO1 CAMPO2 CAMPO3 CAMPO4 CAMPO5
023151 266364 12123   15463 15562
023151 266364 12123   15463 15562
023151 266364 12123   15463 15562
023151 266364 12123   15463 15562
023151 266364 12123   15463 15562
```

---

=========CÓDIGO HTML=========

```
<div>
  <p >Buscar:</p>
<input type="file" accept=".txt" id="file-selector" onclick ="leer()" value="">                     
</div>
<div  id ="divTable">
        <table id="dataTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                 <th>CAMPO1</th>
                 <th>CAMPO2</th>
                 <th>CAMPO3</th>
                 <th>CAMPO4</th>
                 <th>CAMPO5</th>
                 <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
                <tbody id="tbody">
                    <!-- TABLE CONTENT -->
                </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

---

```
<script>

    function leer(){
  
       document.getElementById("file-selector").addEventListener("click", function() {

       let reader = new FileReader();

       reader.addEventListener('load', function(e) {

       let texto = e.target.result;
       
       console.log(texto);
      
       alert("Realizo la lectura del texto")

       let jsonLis = JSON.stringify(texto);

       console.log(jsonLis);
   
     });

     reader.readAsText(document.querySelector('input').files[0]);

   });

  }


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dividí tus acciones en 2 partes porque no tenían sentido como las pusiste. El HTML tiene la tabla vacía, primero seleccionas el archivo y luego click a "Leer":

```
<div>
    <p>Buscar:</p>
    <input type="file" accept=".txt" id="file-selector" value="">
    <br>
    <input type="button" onclick="leer()" value="Leer Archivo">
</div>
<div id="divTable">
    <table id="dataTable">
        <thead id="thead">
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbody">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

El JS:

```
<script>
    function leer() {

        let reader = new FileReader();

        reader.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
            let texto = e.target.result;
            let lineas = texto.split("\r\n");

            addHeaderRow(lineas[0]);

            for (var i = 1; i < lineas.length; i++) {
                addRow(lineas[i]);
            }
        });

        reader.readAsText(document.querySelector('input').files[0]);
    }

    function addRow(line) {
        var tableRef = document.getElementById("tbody");
        var newRow = tableRef.insertRow(0);
        var cells = splitRow(line);

        for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
            var newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
            newCell.innerHTML = cells[i];
        }
    }

    function addHeaderRow(line) {
        var tableRef = document.getElementById("thead");
        var newRow = tableRef.insertRow(0);
        var cells = splitRow(line);

        for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
            var headerCell = document.createElement("th");
            headerCell.innerHTML = cells[i];
            newRow.appendChild(headerCell);
        }
    }

    function splitRow(linea) {
        return linea.split(" ");
    }
</script>
```

El TXT:

```
CAMPO1 CAMPO2 CAMPO3 CAMPO4 CAMPO5
023151 266364 12123 15463 15562
023151 266364 12123 15463 15562
023151 266364 12123 15463 15562
023151 266364 12123 15463 15562
023151 266364 12123 15463 15562
```